# readHTMLTable() returning a List of 0

Tags: r

I am trying to read a table using `readHTML()` function in R. But getting the result - List of 0 and the error message as below:

> "XML content does not seem to be XML:
>   'https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank' "

I have already tried using `library(XML)` and `library(RCurl)` before `readHTMLTable()` function.

I tried below options till now

```
library(XML)

Forbes=readHTMLTable("https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank",as.data.frame = TRUE)
```

Another way.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl) 

URL<- "https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank"

Forbeslist <- readHTMLTable(getURL(URL))
```

getting below error message:

> "XML content does not seem to be XML:
>   'https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank' "

Comment: Could you improve your formatting a little bit? It's hard to read as it is. Just use four spaces to indent code and use backticks around little snippets that you don't want translated into a different language (such as variable and function names).

Comment: And you should try to make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will make sure to consider these points in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

The table on the site is generated by a script. You can see it if you disable scripts in a browser or just download the page using `wget https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank`. R doesn't execute scripts, so it doesn't see any table.